# Add a comment to the table of contents, in the space between "Contents" and the table

Tags: table-of-contents

I'd like to add one or two lines of comments to the table of contents, in the space between the heading "Contents" and the table itself, and I'd like to have a margin of freedom for adjusting the distance of this text from the heading and/or from the list. Any hint? I'm working with the document class "book".

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE. Please elaborate your answer by posting a minimal working example.

Comment: @pushpen.paul what do you not understand in that question? If it's only a minimal setup you can play with, see my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might use the `\addtocontents` macro:

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{5cm}This is a note\vspace{4cm}\par}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{foo}
\chapter{bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably want the `\par` before the `\vspace`.

Comment: @TH. it doesn't matter as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ah. I can never remember what the LaTeX vertical spacing commands do in horizontal mode. Looking at it, it looks like it ends up using a `\vadjust` when not in vertical mode.

Comment: @TH.: Yes, `\vspace` not in vertical mode results in `\vadjust`; yet the tokens specified in the argument of `\addtocontents` should be processed in vertical mode.

Comment: @Skillmon: Why `\vspace*`?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti my bad, I wasn't sure whether `\vspace` does work at the beginning but didn't test it... I'll edit.

Comment: If the document is multiple parts with multiple TOC's, How can you limit its scope to that specific table

Comment: @Silva by using a slightly more complicated second argument for `\addtocontents`. Please ask a new question if you have a new question.

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility: add the text to the definition of the table of contents

*(the original definition is taken from `book.cls` l. 588ff)*

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \lipsum[2]% <- Add your text here
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{bla}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1!  I like people who opposes the “there’s a package for that” philosophy!

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I'm not opposed to packages, some are really helpful or would you really want to make all the coffee stains on your document by hand? :)

Comment: I was joking, of course!  Mine was just an innocent (or at least, I meant it so) pun on the fact that the `tocloft` package does exactly redefine the `\tableofcontents` command, albeit in a less class-specific manner.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Me too :) That's why I suggested such a useful example :)

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is to use the `tocloft` package, which features a `\cftaftertoctitle` command that can be stretched a little bit beyond what it was intended for in order to provide the required addition:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % unrelated to the problem, but I always load it
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lipsum} % only for this example, generates "Lorem ipsum" text

\renewcommand*{\cftaftertoctitle}{%
    \par % necessary
    \nobreak\bigskip % for example
    \itshape % font changes are confined to the note
    This is a note after the title.
    \lipsum*[2]\par
    % \nobreak\vspace{18pt} % uncomment and modify as needed
}



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Fake chapter title}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Fake section title}
\lipsum[2-8]

\section{Another fake title}
\lipsum[9-16]

\end{document}
```

This solution has the advantage of not requiring a pass through the `.toc` file…